# Choosing an Oracle Database Character Set

Tags: oracle, character-set

Does anyone know what is Oracle Database Character Set Name for Polish?

Comment: Use UTF8 (AL32UTF8) which is the default nowadays anyway

Comment: Maybe this witll be helpfull: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm (ISO 8859-2 for polish character set)

Comment: Follow [documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm#sthref144): *At the top of the list of character sets Oracle **recommends for all new system deployment is the Unicode character set AL32UTF8**.*

Comment: I have use character set AL32UTF8. But when I load the file. My string from WROCŁAW become WROCÅAW. any idea?

Comment: How do you load your file? What is the encoding of this file?